# Effort at / of / in shooting?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I was reading a text and came across:

> The coyote population continues to grow despite efforts **at** trapping, shooting, and poisoning the animals.

Now, consider below sentence; is there any difference resulted by using different preposition? In brief, which preposition do you prefer?

> It continues to grow despite efforts **of / in** trapping, shooting, and poisoning the animals.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in meaning between prepositions ***at*** and ***in*** in your example sentences, as far as I can judge, is really subtle.  This is how I understand it.

When you say "*effort **at** something*", it refers to *something* as an undertaking, and calls it *an effort*, emphasizing that some energy/resources are required for it.

When you say "*effort **in** something*", it refers to some part of *something* that is not necessarily easy/simple, and emphasizes that those parts require certain energy/resources for the success.

As StoneyB points out "*effort[s] **to** {infinitive}*" is a more common form.  I share that opinion.

As to the preposition '*of*', it is used to invert a noun adjunct (*noun-noun* sequence) without change in meaning:

> Horse mane >> The mane ***of*** a horse
>   Car engine >> The engine ***of*** a car

In this case one can say "*trapping effort*", or one can say "*effort **of** trapping*", but the meaning is different than with the preposition "**in**" or "**at**".  In a *noun-noun* construct the first noun (the noun adjunct) serves the role of an adjective.

To me the sentence

> The coyote population continues to grow despite efforts **of** trapping, shooting, and poisoning the animals.

somehow just doesn't sound right, most likely because a definite article before "*efforts*" is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

They used "at" because they wanted to say the efforts were *unsuccessful*. That is, they *attempted* to reduce the population, but failed.

A better way to put it, that makes better use of "at":

- Despite efforts at controlling the population (trapping, shooting and poisoning)...

The sentence is not concerned with *how much effort* goes into each of these methods; the point is that **each** method is **an** effort, and these three **efforts** combined have failed to reduce the population.

(of course, one could just as well say "efforts **to control**)